# Pre Match Sub Pattern Not Matching

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate VAT numbers, I have found the follwoing pattern:

```
 $pattern = '/^(
                        (AT)?U[0-9]{8} |                              # Austria
                        (BE)?0[0-9]{9} |                              # Belgium
                        (BG)?[0-9]{9,10} |                            # Bulgaria
                        (CY)?[0-9]{8}L |                              # Cyprus
                        (CZ)?[0-9]{8,10} |                            # Czech Republic
                        (DE)?[0-9]{9} |                               # Germany
                        (DK)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Denmark
                        (EE)?[0-9]{9} |                               # Estonia
                        (EL|GR)?[0-9]{9} |                            # Greece
                        (ES)?[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z] |               # Spain
                        (FI)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Finland
                        (FR)?[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9} |                    # France
                        (GB)?([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}) | # United Kingdom
                        (HU)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Hungary
                        (IE)?[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L |                        # Ireland
                        (IT)?[0-9]{11} |                              # Italy
                        (LT)?([0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12}) |                   # Lithuania
                        (LU)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Luxembourg
                        (LV)?[0-9]{11} |                              # Latvia
                        (MT)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Malta
                        (NL)?[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2} |                      # Netherlands
                        (PL)?[0-9]{10} |                              # Poland
                        (PT)?[0-9]{9} |                               # Portugal
                        (RO)?[0-9]{2,10} |                            # Romania
                        (SE)?[0-9]{12} |                              # Sweden
                        (SI)?[0-9]{8} |                               # Slovenia
                        (SK)?[0-9]{10}                                # Slovakia
                        )$/';


        $match = preg_match($pattern,$vat);
```

However I do not seem to be getting a match. When deleting the rest of the patterns and removing the outer parenthesis I do get a match. I have already had to add the forward slashes to the start and end as it complained about missing ending delimiter. But I do not seem to be able to get this working. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: All inside the parenthesis is a pattern to match. with this, if you make a patter like this: `/(d+),(w+)/` you obtain two patterns that matches like `12,word` or `0123,sometext`. You have comments that no matches with nothing (# Malta #Poland, etc) you must to remove the m

Comment: It will be probably better if you extract country patterns to seperate rows in array (country -> pattern). Then construct global pattern using some string functions like implode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex pattern is VERBOSE, so you need to add [`x` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

> **x (PCRE_EXTENDED)**
>   If this modifier is set, whitespace data characters in the pattern are totally ignored except when escaped or inside a character class, and characters between an unescaped `#` outside a character class and the next newline character, inclusive, are also ignored. This is equivalent to Perl's `/x` modifier, and makes it possible to include commentary inside complicated patterns. Note, however, that this applies only to data characters. Whitespace characters may never appear within special character sequences in a pattern, for example within the sequence `(?(` which introduces a conditional subpattern.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/OnMqyF)

Comment: Added x to the end and worked straight away. Definitely wanted to keep the comments. The demo just helped make life easy. Many thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: A VERBOSE option is helpful with such long regex patterns, and surely the comments make it much more maintainable. A best practice, so to say :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `x` (extended) modifier in your regex. Using `x` allow you to use spaces and text after a `#` in the pattern are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It will be probably better if you extract country patterns to seperate rows in array (country -> pattern). Then construct global pattern using some string functions like implode. Here you go:

```
$vatPatterns = array(
    'Austria'        => '(AT)?U[0-9]{8}',
    'Belgium'        => '(BE)?0[0-9]{9}',
    'Bulgaria'       => '(BG)?[0-9]{9,10}',
    'Cyprus'         => '(CY)?[0-9]{8}L',
    'Czech Republic' => '(CZ)?[0-9]{8,10}',
    'Germany'        => '(DE)?[0-9]{9}',
    'Denmark'        => '(DK)?[0-9]{8}',
    'Estonia'        => '(EE)?[0-9]{9}',
    'Greece'         => '(EL|GR)?[0-9]{9}',
    'Spain'          => '(ES)?[0-9A-Z][0-9]{7}[0-9A-Z]',
    'Finland'        => '(FI)?[0-9]{8}',
    'France'         => '(FR)?[0-9A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}',
    'United Kingdom' => '(GB)?([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})',
    'Hungary'        => '(HU)?[0-9]{8}',
    'Ireland'        => '(IE)?[0-9]S[0-9]{5}L',
    'Italy'          => '(IT)?[0-9]{11}',
    'Lithuania'      => '(LT)?([0-9]{9}|[0-9]{12})',
    'Luxembourg'     => '(LU)?[0-9]{8}',
    'Latvia'         => '(LV)?[0-9]{11}',
    'Malta'          => '(MT)?[0-9]{8}',
    'Netherlands'    => '(NL)?[0-9]{9}B[0-9]{2}',
    'Poland'         => '(PL)?[0-9]{10}',
    'Portugal'       => '(PT)?[0-9]{9}',
    'Romania'        => '(RO)?[0-9]{2,10}',
    'Sweden'         => '(SE)?[0-9]{12}',
    'Slovenia'       => '(SI)?[0-9]{8}',
    'Slovakia'       => '(SK)?[0-9]{1}',
);

$vatGlobalPattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $vatPatterns) . ')$/';

var_dump($vatGlobalPattern);

$vatsToCheck = array(
    'ATU12345678',
    '0123456789',
    'ATU1234',
);

$vatsChecked = array_map(function ($vat) use ($vatGlobalPattern) {
    return preg_match($vatGlobalPattern, $vat) === 1;
}, $vatsToCheck);

var_dump($vatsChecked);
```